# The app reports an exception that it didn't receive the parameter, but it successfully saved it

Tags: c#, sql

I'm working on a school project. The application reads messages from the mailbox(I am using Mailkit nuget) and then creates Alerts from them.

**Alert class**

```
public Alert(string id_MimeMessage = " ", string nameOfAlert = null,DateTime date = default, string element = " ", int user_ID = 0, AlertValue value = default,AlertResult result = default, int clearTime = 0, string email = null)
        {
            this.id = 0;
            this.Id_MimeMessage = id_MimeMessage;
            this.Date = date;
            this.Element = element;
            this.User_ID = user_ID;
            this.NameOfAlert = nameOfAlert;
            this.Value = value;
            this.Result = result;
            this.ClearTime = clearTime;
            this.Email = email;
        }
```

My problem is that as soon as the application reads the email, I get an exception

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The parameterized query '(@message_ID varchar(100),@date datetime,@element varchar(100),@' expects the parameter '@element', which was not supplied.'

However, the Alert is still saved to the Database when I print it.

How is this possible?

**What it looks like in practice**

```
  for (int i = 0; i < inbox.Count; i++)
                        {                           
                            //email message
                            var message = inbox.GetMessage(i, cancel.Token);
                            GetBodyText = message.TextBody ?? message.HtmlBody ?? string.Empty;
                            //To allow the application to read emails that contain HTML
                                
                                 //Here I am avoiding to save duplicates
                                if (!dAOAlert.GetAll().Any(x => x.Id_MimeMessage.Equals(message.MessageId)))
                            {
                                
                                foreach (var item in FindResult(GetBodyText, message))
                                {
                                    //Here I am saving new Alert
                                    dAOAlert.Save(item);
                                    
                                }

                            }

                        }
```

> FIND RESULT METHOD:

```
public List<Alert> FindResult(string text, MimeMessage message)
        {
            return Regex
            .Split(text, @"\r?\n\s*\r?\n")
            .Select(s => new Alert(message.MessageId, s.Contains("PING") ? "PING" : "Backup", message.Date.DateTime, s.Contains("PING") ? s.Split(' ')[0] : s.Split().Where(x => x.StartsWith("(") && x.EndsWith(")") && x.Any(char.IsUpper)).FirstOrDefault(), 3, s.Contains("PING") ? AlertValue.Low : AlertValue.High, s.Contains("Failed") ? AlertResult.FAIL : AlertResult.SUCCESS, 5, "emailTest"))
            .ToList();
        }
```

**SQL SCHEME:**

> CREATE TABLE TestAlert(
>
> id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
>
> id_MimeMessage VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
>
> date_Receive DATETIME NOT NULL,
>
> element VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
>
> AMUser_ID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES AMUser(id),
>
> name_Of_Alert VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
>
> alert_Value VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
>
> alert_Result VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
>
> clear_Time INT NOT NULL,
>
> email VARCHAR(100)
>
> );

> METHOD FOR SAVING NEW ALERT

```
 public void Save(Alert alert)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DatabaseSingleton.connString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string query = "INSERT INTO [TestAlert] (id_MimeMessage, date_Receive, element, AMUser_ID,name_Of_Alert,alert_Value, alert_Result, clear_Time, email)" +
                    "VALUES (@message_ID, @date, @element, @AMUser_ID, @name_Of_Alert,@alert_Value,@alert_Result, @clearTime,@email);";
               
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add("@message_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = alert.Id_MimeMessage ;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime, 50).Value = alert.Date;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@element", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = alert.Element;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@AMUser_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = alert.User_ID;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@name_Of_Alert", SqlDbType.VarChar,100).Value = alert.NameOfAlert;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@alert_Value", SqlDbType.VarChar,100).Value = alert.Value;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@alert_Result", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = alert.Result;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@clearTime", SqlDbType.Int).Value = alert.ClearTime;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar,100).Value = alert.Email;
                    var returnedValue = command.ExecuteScalar();
                    alert.Id = Convert.ToInt32(returnedValue);
                    //MessageBox.Show("SAVED");

                    }
                conn.Close();
            }
           
           
        }
```

**Example of the email:**

> Today at 01:05: (NAME) Failed Backup - The operation encountered an
> error. (NAME) Failed when backing up: A file was not found (NAME)
> DISK_OPEN_ERROR
>
> Today at 01:04: (NAME) Successful Backup - Backed 42,73 MB (compressed
> to 7,32 MB).(Duration: 1 minute)
>
> Today at 00:59: (NAME) Successful Backup - Backed 3,41 GB (compressed
> to 379,17 MB).(Duration: 4 minutes)

I would like to save Alert without exception

Comment: Try changing `var returnedValue = command.ExecuteScalar();` to `var returnedValue = command.ExecuteNonQuery();` See [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately it didn't help. I think the problem could be in `FindResult`

Comment: @user9938 Yeah, the problem is in `FindResult` method, specifically with this part `s.Contains("PING") ? s.Split(' ')[0] : s.Split().Where(x => x.StartsWith("(") && x.EndsWith(")") && x.Any(char.IsUpper)).FirstOrDefault()`